# What is the 3D printer filament (or pellet) most resistant to bending at high heats?

Tags: filament, filament-choice

I'm looking to 3D print a structure that won't deform in high heat, up to about 220 °C. The filament itself can be 3D printed all the way up to about 380 °C.

PEI seems like it could be a viable option. I found some [here](https://www.matterhackers.com/store/l/3dxtech-thermax-pei-175mm-05kg/sk/MHCFSNUC?rcode=GAT9HR&gclid=CjwKCAjwqZPrBRBnEiwAmNJsNsqaaSEcWYtaTv1rIwDKuWgI9xCyinqDgV7bYUUO3zX7-pIA0gDPSBoCclYQAvD_BwE). This PEI filament  specifies the glass transition temperature at 217 °C.

Would this filament work? Are there any other types of materials that would fulfill this engineering requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected operating temperature exceeds the glass transition temperature by 3 °C. This implies that the structure will become weak and can deform under load.

Note that you cannot simply print PEI on a normal machine, it requires a special high temperature capable printer with hot end temperatures up to 400 °C and heated bed over 120 °C up to 160 °C, furthermore it will need a heated chamber (up to about 80 °C) which requires special care to cooling and placement of electronics and motors.

Not having specified what kind of structure you require, you could look into steel.

Answer (score 2):

**[PEEK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyether_ether_ketone)** is also used in applications where dimensional stability (and/or chemical resistance) over a wide range of temperatures is desired. The requirements for printing are similar to those for PEI.

Answer (score 1):

An easier but less simple solution might be to make a PLA 'pattern' that is the right size and shape, then use that to cast your item in aluminium  (melting point ~ 660C) using the 'investment' or 'lost PLA' process.
Links:- 
https://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Printed-Lost-PLA-Investment-Casting-Aluminium/